# jasmine.createSpyObj with properties

Tags: javascript, jasmine

When mocking dependencies in my Angular tests, I usually create a spy object using `jasmine.createSpyObj`:

```
const serviceSpy= jasmine.createSpyObj('MyService', ['method']);
```

then provide it to the TestBed:

```
  providers: [
    {provide: MyService, useValue: serviceSpy}
  ]
```

When I use it in my test, I can then specify the desired return value:

```
serviceSpy.method.and.returnValue(of([...]));
```

Now I also need to mock properties and I cannot find out how it should be done. `createSpyObj` does allow the definition of property names:

```
const serviceSpy= jasmine.createSpyObj('MyService', ['method'], ['property']);
```

but I've tried varies solutions based on the numerous articles and answers out there without any success, e.g.:

```
// Cannot read property 'and' of undefined    
serviceSpy.property.and.returnValue(true);  
// not declared configurable
spyOnProperty(serviceSpy, 'property').and.returnValue(true);  
// no build errors, but value stays 'undefined'
serviceSpy.property = true;
```

The only way I could make it 'half' work is:

```
let fakeValue = true;
const serviceSpy= jasmine.createSpyObj('MyService', ['method'], {'property': fakeValue});
```

The problem here is that it's a one-time set at creation. If I want to change the expected value in the test, it does not work.

```
fakeValue = false;
serviceSpy.property ==> stays to the initial value 'true';
```

Does there exist a solution to both mock methods and properties by creating a spy object, or should I create my own fake class on which I can then use `spyOn` and `spyOnProperty`?

I would also like to know what the usage is of the properties array in the `createSpyObj` definition. So far I have not seen any example on the web that explains it.

Comment: When you say you can't declare multiple, do you mean e.g. `jasmine.createSpyObj('MyService', ['foo'], {'bar': 0, 'baz': 1})` doesn't create an object with `foo`, `bar` and `baz`? From [the implementation](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/cd1131354bea551ef11478e313fe66fb11721cf4/src/core/SpyFactory.js#L38-L50) it looks like `propertyNames` can be an array of string `key`s or an object `{[key]: value}`.

Comment: You're right. I'm able to define multiple properties this way. The problem is that it's a one-time initial value. I cannot change it in the test with a new expectation. I updated the question to clarify it more.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/spying_on_properties) (emphasis mine):

> You can create a spy object with several properties on it quickly by
> passing an array or hash of properties as a third argument to
> `createSpyObj`. In this case you won’t have a reference to the created
> spies, so **if you need to change their spy strategies later, you will
> have to use the `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` approach**.
>
> ```
> it("creates a spy object with properties", function() {
>   let obj = createSpyObj("myObject", {}, { x: 3, y: 4 });
>   expect(obj.x).toEqual(3);
>
>   Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, "x").get.and.returnValue(7);
>   expect(obj.x).toEqual(7);
> });
> ```

Spied properties are *descriptors* (see e.g. [`Object.defineProperty` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)), so to access the spy objects you need to get the descriptor object then interact with the `get` and `set` methods defined on it.

---

In TypeScript, the compiler needs a bit of help. [`createSpyObj`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/d063d0175b3eb59a7a4cc5e64992f8a220d9a910/types/jasmine/index.d.ts#L292-L295) returns either `any` or `SpyObj<T>`, and a `SpyObj` only defines the *methods* as being spied on:

```
type SpyObj<T> = T & {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Func ? T[K] & Spy<T[K]> : T[K];
               // |     if it's a     |    spy on it     | otherwise leave
               // |     callable      |                  | it alone
};
```

So to access `.and` on the descriptor's getter, you'll need [optional chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining) (as `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` may return `undefined`) and a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to a [`Spy`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/d063d0175b3eb59a7a4cc5e64992f8a220d9a910/types/jasmine/index.d.ts#L959-L965):

```
(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, "x")?.get as Spy<() => number>).and.returnValue(7);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-VkXIe7FuOkBZOKIUnk84QVs4bIhQ8OhtZCC+C9ksgAJSwWWGloAgmgaCYBELxvBocQAD5sBAs5fOCu5PC0YCvO884CPykjRHwb7Dl+mA-no-6AcB4QANYgIQUDjJcEBQdws4GB0IzkZR1HzqiEDnAx87Xjwt5ZCE-Z7C+EBfvkhSuiAFzcXE6Ezpha4buicCYgiOJ7leyAPsep5IDhV43n0AkQNpT4vjhn7fr+hAAUBIHIWBkHQbOcJYoikLPA5qFyYQmEQNh5K4VZhE2cREQsVRnFOfRjFvBAEVsRxXEGDx0iKTaIChMpxLIFeABkJKBbOADSTHxRRkXnGhnElTxhl3n2A4iVxxU8QVYTSa1sk1a1gprm8OBoKMmAoJlADCpTADY4S9iM9XGUJKBxKwOG1AAVGtEAAEK+SgiyYGa7wbIsmU2EQczaqgk02BkM5RCw8zAMAFLgFS8qlHSHTjOKLTnftIR6GKEApH0V1PSeQSQJNLCZM+4ojMh5TQHsmXYBAoCysjmUoJNyqYPgph6DdEBrbUOH8lEAgwFAUAY3o8iBetm07ag+2HRox2ned8xLGDU36lAuxgPdF1PS94kIyd8RJCkaBjBsnS2Jzv2+TowR8xDpM4QaQuU9LyRmAz5JM9tu1s06R0-WdquXTjT03eOk69i4IuPc9lKFMrjtJH0nYQDKNh0nDUB8-rstMS2PAk2TgWOzYzuuM2rYCIkBtoPiEAGOODKDdNs0xEbZImyze0HRbHNW9ztvXRkT0AZOrv2GLHuS6jE4+-0ITOEEYt21N0fk3XE42HreEEURdnhFnQFfGYed6DEBerRtpus2XYHK9bF2833DtPY3zevZ7P0Gv0N7Dj9Sz2DY0Sw0E7e9J3-vBEHPfPbvA+x-vGdj9ZtkkRNJ6ABJPQowoAzQXkvRmK8S7mw3pXG2O8a5UCgK0L8o1+gH3dkfVuKwz58QvlLK+N9pzPm9o-P2YC5Y-RQa0F6GDIB90-uSWhYB0G+z1oA4AICwEQKgcbGBZt16WyllvHmyxd5qFNGgVoWDxZvRPsMHABCyCX0WNfW+2R74aA7pQlwytpF0KYVrQKhjhYZy4Tw8B+dC4QGLkI9mm8q5IPtrkWw4A5EoAxjIt+GwgIoFIhvKhQQVbMLJBgOk5iBAADcoD2CyLYk2uBAjENCd3H8ISbD7SelAHQqBPR6EypFchvsQgB1ft3LAe0mKxJxmAA4agwktEwNEkA9ddE2B2iUMoFQM6xPiYKBQA0zDDVGhASxoDrFzT4kZQSA5lrL02ucKWp9lGQFUUQ9RJDgkn1xiY8k7hVA+USSvP8YsSlP3KRDbuuyxb7LJHHAQ08c5zz4ScpZUsW4QGiaUJGkVbnPXufIwo3TygCDElSSSby5BCjkMMoaI1MphD-NkCBvF+JzL2AswK8TfYLFEEhFCGg1zQOZg48uTjEHLFhvqSayzjAJA0IsFgCDRbPVaE3Z6yERqkV8R-buCxgYJEgHFfCWQFgHA6JAN2EAWygA0FMDYIcfojXyKUDoXQei+0GMMRpQK+70sFkyvWHUbGLNXqXRxrLxGkLcRLUFjI+XXSVQYgc9ThhsuBSMTAv16D2FNIOH5PS9Ux3JC3B1ZAg3gpwVC-OGdTUL3eRauBIiuZUtteG35tgYa92dTcqWOw9jupGDKr5Z0-UBu+VmkIcUXAtjlkLJuUqXojROl3KWRl5Y-S+UG8oIRgDX3UE0zNPSR6jjUL22wAh-4RAhRJDKfC0gEmhaS5NwiK6iOcdS7ItKnq9kwORHN7883Ks3TbMWcqQAKpwC6q2CQCYDohoW-Yuqml933eRMgow9ACFmvGogK6BFLItFys9Lqvk+tcvWT6ETabRPgaermFb7AQ0nXME6Iw3ixPIjkYdtg4MgHOFASNpQOKYmgyeOdehY0L3-REM1q7zggcpeBnBISoPX0yhgFQ+wjo2srsh1DWb0Ogyw1AHDIacLcdUAAdW1CR4AZHFScayF+HjYAaNLqyvRxN5rYHrpYzamlSxjA6AAKKARcEevmXdEOhJlSZ3JTjBPPknZJwKjnzOWdcFQGwGhPJEtohACzxh04EiTTJjDIS+4bxeFMDQvlr4mVfsEn11sWVSxcPYLUeh1WtF1DADeKR9rwf0TjEYKQvUQzRhhepvRt7bpyPlvUTTmsmqIIM9cGVM7KaDlRmj6LZmNSxXpQKs1BsNTICOMcw8fILiXHEcjnGAAy9hyLhDeKMCU5wvw2ASMAMAaRmq7f25AFOIBWloHSqYHrhoVNqdUAN+amKX0L1G+Scbz3hzTYyLN6cc5FyxFuxR1b63dikUBvoI7vh-v+XiBdw23ZuvAmwKXD0bTh58KHJ9mZk3x2PKYltuWBgFuw5h-RUqcUEqZ2qgYWqQW-w2EIFQL4rwUAo7AHtMw4R+RxHYHDwpl3+pnwRWMxnzPWf2HZ6jk6aALgOuxeSYIEvwBs453tNw4o0ACHOA6lgKAEitENEx1oc9o34T-mFcIY1DfOCoGZgAjgkUo+KTeDS09TWmWB6Y4VrDYeshSiO4C8hoXwetQLvE6z2G3Rv7dO5dxYN3EpkBfvsDIsAPkWB0lPlkHypPPd0yC-0hJQyRejKRQBnHGLhuDmQItRX75x0yhnlOZ5s8ZF8J-jGhdZrybZAJCirIgGyS7wEFw+e-CyTiPrmOmbk4BDq-2ujmfnfl1mqFEAA)

Comment: I think it's close. but this is not working in typescript (Angular). 'and' is a property of a spy object. `Property 'and' does not exist on type '() => any'`.

Comment: @Ronald it works in the JS, which tells you it's a types problem rather than a functionality problem. I've added one way to fix that.

Comment: thanks for the very clear explanations and related links. It's a little more complex than I initial expected, but it will help my testing a lot.

Comment: @jonrsharpe This is great and really helped. For me I needed to prefix Spy with "jasmine." otherwise Typescript didn't understand what Spy was:
(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, "x")?.get as jasmine.Spy<() => number>).and.returnValue(7);

Comment: What if the value changes in the component and I want to check if it was set correctly? For example myObject is a service. And I have `let myServiceMock = createSpyObj('MyService', [], {prop1: {} })` and in the component I have a function in which I say `MyService.prop1 = {value: 1}`. And then in the test I want to check that when this function is called, `myServiceMock.prop.value` is set to 1. But in the test, prop1 is still an empty object

Comment: @bokkie at a certain point maybe your test double should just be a vanilla object, with regular properties, rather than have get/set spies?

Comment: @jonrsharpe well, they are private fields exposed through getters and setters...thing is that if initialise the spy property with an empty object, changing it in the component doesn't reflect back in the test. it remains with the initialised value, empty object...

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have a question on this (but ok, with null instead of {}, but same result) with no solution to it. If you have time, you can have a look (on the bottom there is a simplified sccenario): 
"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73707497/jasmine-null-mocked-service-property-value-doesnt-change-when-changed-in-compon"

Comment: @bokkie _"they are private fields exposed through getters and setters"_ and the consumer shouldn't have to care about that at all; that's the _point_ of get/set vs Java-style getThing() and setThing() methods, you can start with a vanilla property then guard access if and when needed. It's not clear what `browserStorageService` is, because you're really not _using_ TypeScript, but the point of the test double of `MyService` is that your component doesn't have to know that.

Answer (score 30):

Thank you so much @jonrsharpe! I just added a function so I could do:

```
spyPropertyGetter(spy, 'propName').and.returnValue(...)
```

Which is defined as:

```js
function spyPropertyGetter<T, K extends keyof T>(
  spyObj: jasmine.SpyObj<T>,
  propName: K
): jasmine.Spy<() => T[K]> {
  return Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(spyObj, propName)?.get as jasmine.Spy<() => T[K]>;
}
```

Comment: I might be inclined to use generics here, so the `returnValue` can be type-safe: function `function spyPropertyGetter<T, K extends keyof T>(spyObj: SpyObj<T>, propName: K): Spy<() => T[K]> { /* ... */ }`.

Answer (score 3):

This one will also do the job :)

```
const serviceSpy= jasmine.createSpyObj('MyService', ['method']);
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(serviceSpy, "method").value.and.returnValue("test");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to spy on observable properties, but the above method doesn't work for me. Finally, I'm using.

```
let userService: jasmine.SpyObj<UserService>
let isUserInfoLoaded$ = new BehaviorSubject(false)
beforeEach(()=>{
    userService = jasmine.createSpyObj<UserService>('UserService',[],{
        isUserInfoLoaded$
    })
    //...
})
it('should....',()=>{
    isUserInfoLoaded$.next(true)
    //...
})
```