# Jasmine spy on service with get property

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner

I have an `AuthenticationService` that exposes a get property:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {
  private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<AuthenticatedUserModel>;

  get currentUserValue(): AuthenticatedUserModel {
    return this.currentUserSubject.value;
  }
}
```

This service is used in a custom pipe that I created. In order to verify that the pipe is working as expected I was trying to write some tests, but I am struggling to mock the get property. I found this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64560390/jasmine-createspyobj-with-properties) which was very helpful. I tried all the below options to mock the get property but unfortunately no luck so far.

```
// Property currentUserValue does not have access type get
spyOnProperty(authenticationServiceSpy, 'currentUserValue', 'get').and.returnValue(undefined);

// Cannot read property 'and' of undefined
(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(authenticationServiceSpy, 'currentUserValue')?.get as jasmine.Spy<() => AuthenticatedUserModel>).and.returnValue(undefined);
((Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(authenticationServiceSpy, 'currentUserValue')?.get as jasmine.Spy<() => AuthenticatedUserModel>) as jasmine.Spy).and.returnValue(undefined);
```

One of the answers in the Stackoverflow post I mentioned states that this is a types problem. I thought referring to the object as a `spy` would resolve this issue but that is not the case.

Hope you guys could help me or point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You should use spyOnProperty :

```
it("allows you to create spies for either type", function() {
  spyOnProperty(someObject, "myValue", "get").and.returnValue(30);
  spyOnProperty(someObject, "myValue", "set").and.callThrough();
});
```

You can read documentation here :
https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/spying_on_properties

Comment: Unfortunately, I still got the same error. Am I missing something?