# How do I write a test for the following method in (jasmine + karma) that has ComponentFactoryResolver & ApplicationRef injected in the constructor

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I'm learning angular testing with jasmine and karma. I came across this **showBanner()** method in my project and don't know how to proceed further. This is a service method which creates a banner component with the given params and has ComponentFactoryResolver and ApplicationRef injected in the constructor.

I did some research but couldn't find any examples relating to this. How do I mock the constructor dependencies, specifically ApplicationRef. I read it somewhere that it is not necessary to mock ApplicationRef in the providers array in the testbed but I keep getting this error -> **TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'instance')** for the showBanner method line 1, which accesses the components property of appliationRef.

Here is the complete service method

```
import { ApplicationRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, Injectable, ViewContainerRef } from "@angular/core";
import { BannerComponent } from "src/app/components/banner/banner.component";
import { BannerSeverity } from "src/app/utils/utils";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BannerService {
  private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver;                                 // Reference to component factory resolver
  banners : Array<any> = [];                                                  // Array to store all the banners

  /**
   * Constructor
   */
  constructor(
    resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private applicationRef: ApplicationRef) {
      this.resolver = resolver;
  }

  /**
   * Function called to show the banner with the specified configuration
   */
  public showBanner(severity: BannerSeverity, message: string, dismissible?: boolean, appendTo?: ViewContainerRef, moreInfo?: string ): void {
    let globalViewContainerRef = this.applicationRef.components[0].instance.viewContainerRef;
    let factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(BannerComponent);
    let component = null;
    if (appendTo) {
      component = appendTo.createComponent(factory);
    } else if (globalViewContainerRef) {
      component = globalViewContainerRef.createComponent(factory);
    }
    if (component) {
      let banner = component.instance;
      banner.severity = BannerSeverity[severity];
      banner.message = message;
      banner.dismissible = dismissible;
      banner.moreInfo = moreInfo;
      banner.dismissed.subscribe(() => {
        component.destroy();
      });
      this.banners.push(banner);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my test file

```
import { ApplicationRef, ComponentFactoryResolver } from "@angular/core";
import { fakeAsync, flush, TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { BannerSeverity } from "src/app/utils/utils";
import { getTypicalSetup } from "src/testing/typical-setup";
import { BannerService } from "./banner.service";

/**
 * Test cases for banner service.
 */
describe('BannerService', () => {
  const mock = getTypicalSetup();
  let bannerService: BannerService;
  let BANNERS;
  let componentFactoryResolverSpy;

  /**
   * Run some shared setup before each of the specs.
   */
  beforeEach(fakeAsync(() => {
    componentFactoryResolverSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj<ComponentFactoryResolver>('ComponentFactoryResolver', ['resolveComponentFactory']);
    //Configure the test bed.
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [...mock.imports],
      providers: [
        ...mock.providers,
        BannerService,
        { provide: ComponentFactoryResolver, useValue: componentFactoryResolverSpy },
      ],
    });
    bannerService = TestBed.inject(BannerService);
    //Banners array with wasDismissed property.
    BANNERS = [
      { wasDismissed: false },
      { wasDismissed: false },
    ];
  }));

  /**
   * Test to ensure the service is created.
   */
  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(bannerService).toBeDefined();
  });

  /**
   * Test to ensure that the showBanner method creates a banner
   * based on various parameters.
   */
  describe('#showBanner', () => {
    it('should create a banner with severity and message parameters passed', fakeAsync(() => {
      //Arrange
      const severity: BannerSeverity = BannerSeverity.critical;
      const message: string = "Test Message";

            //Act
      bannerService.showBanner(severity, message);
            flush();

            //Assert
      expect(bannerService.banners[0]).toBeDefined();
        }));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe mock it the same way as `ComponentFactoryResolver`.

```
import { ApplicationRef, ComponentFactoryResolver } from "@angular/core";
import { fakeAsync, flush, TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { BannerSeverity } from "src/app/utils/utils";
import { getTypicalSetup } from "src/testing/typical-setup";
import { BannerService } from "./banner.service";

/**
 * Test cases for banner service.
 */
describe('BannerService', () => {
  const mock = getTypicalSetup();
  let bannerService: BannerService;
  let BANNERS;
  let componentFactoryResolverSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<ComponentFactoryResolver>;
  // add this line
  let applicationRefSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<ApplicationRef>;

  /**
   * Run some shared setup before each of the specs.
   */
  beforeEach(fakeAsync(() => {
    componentFactoryResolverSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj<ComponentFactoryResolver>('ComponentFactoryResolver', ['resolveComponentFactory']);
    // mock how you like
    applicationRefSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj<ApplicationRef>('ApplicationRef', {}, { components: [{ instance: { viewContainerRef: {} } }] });
    //Configure the test bed.
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [...mock.imports],
      providers: [
        ...mock.providers,
        BannerService,
        { provide: ComponentFactoryResolver, useValue: componentFactoryResolverSpy },
        // add mock
        { provide: ApplicationRef, useValue: applicationRefSpy },
      ],
    });
    bannerService = TestBed.inject(BannerService);
    //Banners array with wasDismissed property.
    BANNERS = [
      { wasDismissed: false },
      { wasDismissed: false },
    ];
  }));

  /**
   * Test to ensure the service is created.
   */
  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(bannerService).toBeDefined();
  });

  /**
   * Test to ensure that the showBanner method creates a banner
   * based on various parameters.
   */
  describe('#showBanner', () => {
    it('should create a banner with severity and message parameters passed', fakeAsync(() => {
      //Arrange
      const severity: BannerSeverity = BannerSeverity.critical;
      const message: string = "Test Message";

            //Act
      bannerService.showBanner(severity, message);
            flush();

            //Assert
      expect(bannerService.banners[0]).toBeDefined();
        }));
  });
});
```

Check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64560773/7365461 on how to mock properties with `createSpyObj`.