# How to Mock Angular service Emitter and return Subscription

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have the following code in my Component, that I would like to test

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authService.loggedInSignal.subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data)
      if (data) {
        this.planFeatures = this.authService.getProfileData().planFeatures;
        console.log(this.planFeatures)
      }
    });
  }
```

For that purpose, I mock the authService, but not sure how to test further.
I would like to verify that subscription is fired and to test inside code

So far I did

```
describe('UpgradeSorageButtonComponent', () => {
  let component: UpgradeSorageButtonComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<UpgradeSorageButtonComponent>;
  let authService: AuthService;
  let mockAuthService = {
    loggedInSignal: {
      subscribe: {}
    },
    
    getProfileData() {return {};}
  };

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [UpgradeSorageButtonComponent],
      imports: [RouterTestingModule],
      providers: [{provide: AuthService, useValue: mockAuthService}]
    }).compileComponents();

    authService = TestBed.inject(AuthService);
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UpgradeSorageButtonComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  fit('should attach to subscriber', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(authService.loggedInSignal, 'subscribe').and.returnValue(true)
  }));
});
```

but getting an error that type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Subscription'

Can someone help with how to properly mock the service and do tests for that piece of code?
Thanks

Comment: A call to subscribe should return a subscription, not a boolean. But I wouldn't mock the observable itself, it's easy to create one using e.g. `of(value)` or `subject.asObservable()`. I wrote about this on my blog, for example: https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/Apr/16/async-angular-tests.html.

Answer (score 2):

The first `fixture.detectChanges()` you call is when `ngOnInit` is called.

Since, `ngOnInit` has `this.authService.loggedInSignal.subscribe`, it is important that it is mocked and returning an observable value before this `fixture.detectChanges()`.

Follow the comments with !! for more details.

```
// !! I would use a spy object, it makes constructions of spies easier
let mockAuthService: jasmine.SpyObj<AuthService>;

beforeEach(async () => {
    mockAuthService = jasmine.createSpyObj<AuthService>('AuthService', [ 'getProfileData'], { loggedInSignal: of(true) });
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [UpgradeSorageButtonComponent],
      imports: [RouterTestingModule],
      providers: [{provide: AuthService, useValue: mockAuthService}]
    }).compileComponents();
     // !! don't need the below line
    // authService = TestBed.inject(AuthService);
  });

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UpgradeSorageButtonComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    authService.loggedInSignal.and.returnValue(of(true));
    // !!!~ ngOnInit is called here
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

I like using Spy Objects because it makes mocking much easier.

Check this [link](https://luardo.medium.com/testing-with-mocks-spies-using-createspyobj-in-angular-1e31bf7f6147) out on how to use Spy Objects and check this [link](https://testing-angular.com/) on how to unit test in Angular as a whole. The 2nd link is really good.

Comment: thanks for the valuable info, unfortunately mockAuthService.loggedInSignal.and.returnValue(of(true)); has issue for 'end.returnValue' which is: Property 'and' does not exist on type 'EventEmitter<any>'

Comment: Oops, I thought `loggedInSignal` was a method. Checkout my edit on the line right after `beforeEach(async () => {`. I am not sure if my answer will work but I imagine it will work. What you're looking to do, this is the overall answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64560773/7365461.

Comment: Thanks, that would work, but unfortunately, there was a mistake in my service. I use EventEmitter instead of Subject and that is what causes me those headaches. What I did is

 const AuthServiceStub = {
  loggedInSignal: new Subject<any>(),
  getProfileData() {
    return {};
  },
  notifyLogin() {
    this.loggedInSignal.next(true);
  },
};
Which emulates the behavior that I have. Thanks for the help. At least I discover an issue with the service, which will solve later.

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the `fixture.detectChanges();` from the `beforeEach` call, then call the `ngOnInit` in your test and -if you spied the code from the `authService`-, you should `tick()` the call to "enter" the subscription callback.

```
fit('should attach to subscriber', fakeAsync(() => {
    ...//Setup test (if necessary)
    spyOn(authService.loggedInSignal, 'subscribe').and.returnValue(true);
    componente.ngOnInit();
    tick();
    expect(thingInsideSubscription);
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres my mock router service, which has a Behaviorsubject that many components subscribe to in their OnInit hooks..... I am providing this service and have a convenience method 'emit', which is what calls next on my Behaviorsubject during testing....

```
class MockRouterUrlStateSvc {
  private _currentRouterUrlState$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

  get currentRouterUrlState$() {
    return this._currentRouterUrlState$.asObservable();
  }

  public emit(value: any) {
    this._currentRouterUrlState$.next(value);
  }
}
```

Your test can look something like the following:

```
class MockAuthService {
// BehaviorSubject with initial value of true
    _loggedInSignal$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);

    get loggedInSignal() {
        return this._loggedInSignal$.asObservable();
    }

    emit(value: boolean) {
        this._loggedInSignal$.next(value);
    }

    getProfileData() {
        return {};
    }
}

describe('UpgradeSorageButtonComponent', () => {
  let component: UpgradeSorageButtonComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<UpgradeSorageButtonComponent>;
  let authService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [UpgradeSorageButtonComponent],
      imports: [RouterTestingModule],
      providers: [{provide: AuthService, useClass: MockAuthService}]
    }).compileComponents();

    authService = TestBed.inject(AuthService);
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UpgradeSorageButtonComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  fit('should attach to subscriber and get true value initially', () => {
    authService.loggedInsignal.subscribe((isLoggedIn) => {
        expect(isLoggedIn).toBeTrue();
    })
  });

  fit('should have emitted false value inside onInit', () => {
    authService.emit(false);
    component.ngOnInit();
    // test stuff happening inside your OnInit based on a false login
  });

  describe('Other stuff', () => {
    it('should not log you in with a false observable value', () => {
      authService.emit(false);
      tick();
      authService.isLoggedInSignal.subscribe((isLoggedIn) => {
        expect(isLoggedIn).toBeFalse();
        // other stuff to test if the user isnt logged in
    })
    })

    it('same as above with jasmine marbles', () => {
      const emissions$ = hot('-a', { a: authService.emit(false) });
      authService.isLoggedInSignal.subscribe((isLoggedIn) => {
        expect(isLoggedIn).toBeFalse();
      });
    });
  });
});
```