# I got and error: TypeError: this.todos$.pipe is not a function when create an jasmine.SpyObj as a fack service

Tags: angular, unit-testing, mocking, jasmine

Here is a simple todo list component:
[image]
Here is my test case:

```
fdescribe('TodoListComponent With FackService', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TodolistComponent>;
  let component: TodolistComponent;
  let fackTodoService: jasmine.SpyObj<TodoService>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    fackTodoService = jasmine.createSpyObj<TodoService>('TodoService', {
      todolist$: of(mocktodos),
      currentTodoList: [],
      getTodos: of(mocktodos),
      deleteTodo: undefined,
      addTodo: of(mocktodos[0]),
    });

    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TodolistComponent],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: TodoService,
          useValue: fackTodoService,
        },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TodolistComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should do something', () => {});
});
```

after I trigger this test, it report an error as follow:
[image]

It seems the mocked service cannot init these data when creating the fixture...
Can I get some help for it, I cannot find effect solution for it... Thank you gays~!

Comment: What is the import where the `of` function comes from? (please share the imports as well in your question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd argument here in `jasmine.createSpyObj` is for methods, the third argument is for `instance variables`.

So imagine this is what you want to mock:

```
export class AnyThing {
  instanceVariable = 2;
  
  method() {
    return 3;
  }
}
```

It would be:

```
let mockAnything: jasmine.SpyObj<Anything>;
...
mockAnything = jasmine.createSpyObj<Anything>('Anything', { method: jasmine.createSpy() }, { instanceVariable: 2 });
```

It can be shortened to:

```
mockAnything = jasmine.createSpyObj<Anything>('Anything', ['method'], { instanceVariable: 2 });
```

All that to say, change this line:

```
fackTodoService = jasmine.createSpyObj<TodoService>('TodoService', {
      todolist$: of(mocktodos),
      currentTodoList: [],
      getTodos: of(mocktodos),
      deleteTodo: undefined,
      addTodo: of(mocktodos[0]),
    });
```

To this:

```
// Add an extra object here for the mock methods after 'TodoService'
fackTodoService = jasmine.createSpyObj<TodoService>('TodoService', {}, {
      todolist$: of(mocktodos),
      currentTodoList: [],
      getTodos: of(mocktodos),
      deleteTodo: undefined,
      addTodo: of(mocktodos[0]),
    });
```

`todolist$` is an instance variable and not a method and that's why we need to use the 3rd argument.

Here is some documentation on what you would like: [jasmine.createSpyObj with properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64560390/7365461)